# Erro: r Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filas')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, tablas

Estoy creando una tabla con los datos guardado en mi coleccion de firebase, cuando intento pintarlos en cada parte de la tabla me genera el siguiente error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filas')

Este es mi codigo, no se que estoy haciendo mal:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getLastDocumentOfTheCollection } from "../Firebase/firebase.config";

const GeneratedReport = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLastDocumentOfTheCollection(setData);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container-ReportGenerated">
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <table className="containerTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>{data.filas.fila1.campo}</th>
              <th>{data.filas.fila2.campo}</th>
              {data?.columnas?.columna1?.data.map((columns, i) =>
                columns === "" ? <th key={i}></th> : <th key={i}>{columns}</th>
              )}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              {data?.filas?.fila1?.data.map((rows, i) => (
                <tr>{rows}</tr>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GeneratedReport;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const [data, setData] = useState(null);` -> esto esta inicializando tu state `data` como `null`. En el primer render, `data` es `null`. Al momento de que React trata de hacer render a `data.filas.fila1` es donde falla.

Tendrias que hacer algo como:

```
const GeneratedReport = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLastDocumentOfTheCollection(setData);
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <></>;
    // o tambien:
    // return null;
    // return <>Cargando...</>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container-ReportGenerated">
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <table className="containerTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>{data.filas.fila1.campo}</th>
              <th>{data.filas.fila2.campo}</th>
              {data?.columnas?.columna1?.data.map((columns, i) =>
                columns === "" ? <th key={i}></th> : <th key={i}>{columns}</th>
              )}
            </tr>
            <tr>
              {data?.filas?.fila1?.data.map((rows, i) => (
                <tr>{rows}</tr>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Nunca setas tu 'data' y tiene un estado de Null por defecto por lo que al renderizarse tu componente intentara sacar el campo filas de Null en la parte

```
<th>{data.filas.fila1.campo}</th>
<th>{data.filas.fila2.campo}</th>
```

usa:

```
<th>{data?.filas.fila1.campo}</th>
<th>{data?.filas.fila2.campo}</th>
```